# How to specify Navigate url of hyperlink itemtemplate in RowCommand event of Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In my `Gridview` I have a hyperlink as itemtemplate (Not link button) . I want to specify its navigate url in row command event of gridview.Because each hyperlink will redirect to different pdf file.

How is it possible? I have tried like this, but Navigate link of hyperlink is not appearing .

```
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="true" HeaderText="Certificates" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#98272d" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <ItemTemplate >  
        <asp:HyperLink  ID="lb_certificate"   runat="server"  ForeColor="Black" 
          CommandName="cc" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("student_id")%>'>Certificate</asp:HyperLink >
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField >

protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    string st_id = Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument.ToString());

    if (e.CommandName == "cc")
    {
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((HyperLink)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
        HyperLink lnkbtn = (HyperLink)row.FindControl("lb_certificate");
        string ss = st_id + "Cc.pdf";
        string year="2014";
        string path = Server.MapPath("~/results/certificates/" + st_id + "/" + year + "/");

        lnkbtn.NavigateUrl = path + s_certificate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you need **RowCommand** or even a **TemplateField** here, you can achieve it by only using **HyperLinkField** like:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField Text="Certificate" DataNavigateUrlFields="student_id"  
     DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/results/certificates/{0}/{0}Cc.pdf" />
```

**Edit:** For including year if it will remain constant then you can use.

```
<asp:HyperLinkField Text="Certificate" DataNavigateUrlFields="student_id"  
     DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/results/certificates/{0}/2014/{0}Cc.pdf" />
```

And If it is dynamic then you should use **RowDataBound** Event like

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
         HyperLink lnkbtn = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("lb_certificate");
         int year = DateTime.Now.Year; //Or your Variable where year is stored.

         // If you are binding with Collection of Object, you can use this 
         //var data = (ObjectClass)e.Row.DataItem;
         //lnkbtn.NavigateUrl = "~/results/certificates/" + data.student_id + "/" + year + "/" + data.student_id  + "Cc.pdf";

         //If you are binding with DataTable
         var data = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
         lnkbtn.NavigateUrl = "~/results/certificates/" + data["student_id"] + "/" + year + "/" + data["student_id"] + "Cc.pdf";
    }
}
```

and now you need to use **HyperLink** control in **templatefield** instead on **HyperLinkField**.

Comment: please see my edited question. I have to specify the year too as a path. how is it declared on .aspx ?

Comment: no this year is a variable. its value may changed on year by year .

Comment: Ok, So how are you gonna to access this year value ie you will get it from current date, or you will pass it some other way?

Comment: yes as current date. actually I want this in row command. Because for each row this year will be defferent. and file name too

Comment: So how will you get this different year and file name for particular row?

Comment: from sql query  . each row has unique student id .based on this it will redirect to different file name .

Comment: In your binding object, you have year and file name. right? or you will fetch this information by student_id?

Comment: this file(pdf) is created on a folder for individual student. file name is same as student_id. and year is current year. each row consists diff.students. so how can I implement it on rowdatabound? it is possible through rowcommand, Is'nt it?

Answer (score 0):

Bind your Hyperlink in gridview

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lb_certificate" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" CommandName="cc"
     NavigateUrl='<%#"~/results/certificates/"+Eval("student_id")+"Cc.pdf" %>' CommandArgument='<%#Eval("student_id")%>'>Certificate</asp:HyperLink>
```